# Session expires before session timeout

Tags: java, session, spring-mvc, timeout, session-timeout

To keep session alive I am pinging server for every 30 seconds, if there is any activity from user. But sometimes(not consistently happening) even after pinging, the server doesn't renew the session. Session timeout is 30 minutes.
First request is sent at 12:27 and the next at 12:35.....But for the second request I am getting unauthorized 401 error. I am using java on server side and IE10 for browsing.  Unfortunately, my reputation is too low to post images of response headers of both requests. Thanks in advance. 
[image] [image]

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Use this definition if using a Java EE 6 container This also stops Eclipse 
    from complaining that 3.0 is not a valid version -->
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation=" 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <!-- Session Configuration -->
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you post some code now?

Comment: Thanks raju for response.

Comment: You will need to post the pertinent part of your code - obviously that which sends the ping - and advise of what authentication mechanism you have for the application.

Comment: how do u solve your problem at the end of the day? I am facing a similar problem. Thanks in advance